# Wrong currency unit in Kendo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, displayformat

In my website I use the Kendo-grid.
In that grid, there is a column "Amount" with these values:
[image: Amount-column in Kendo Grid]

You see that there are dollar-signs before the amounts, but I want euro-signs.

The globalization-culture settings are correct, because when I show an amount outside the grid, it shows me the amount with a euro-sign.

I'm developing this website with ASP.NET MVC5.
In my model I have this property:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

You see that I format my string to currency (and my globalization-culture settings are correct)

Could anyone help me please?

Note: It is not an option to convert the amount to a string, because I have to sort that column. And with strings, it is unable to sort numbers like normal decimals. Strings will be sorted like "1, 11, 2, 20, 3" instead of "1, 2, 3, ..."

Comment: No idea, but I'd think it was a UI thing, something to config in kendo. Also, you can throw down the text column *and* your number column, display the text and sort by the (hidden) number column. Not optimal but a workaround.

Comment: Yes, I have tried your suggestion, but the user needs to have the option to choose an ascending or descending sorting when they click on the columnheader.

Comment: You could probably hack that as well.  Anyhow, the real solution is getting Kendo to use the correct format.  Good luck.

Comment: I thought it was possible to change the currency unit by setting the right culture. But that didn't change the currency unit in my kendo grid. It did change the currency unit outside the kendo grid...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say you have included the correct Globalization settings how are you doing this e.g. via web.config like:

```
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
  </system.web>
```

or via C# e.g.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
```

Assuming these are the ways you are setting the culture for your site have you also include the relevant Kendo Culture script onto your site:

eg.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2015.1.511/cultures/kendo.culture.en-GB.min.js")"></script>
```

**Note: change version and culture settings to your version and required culture e.g. fr-FR, en-US etc**
and then setting the included culture like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      kendo.culture("en-GB");
</script>
```

**Note: Change the en-GB for whatever culture you have specified in the culture script.**

This will then set all the kendo controls use the same culture and you don't have to specify it per control.

see this link for more details: [Kendo Globalization Help](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/overview)

Hopefully this will help you out. Any issues let me know and hopefully we can find out why the en-US setting is being used (it is the default language for the kendo controls)

Comment: I will try that monday