# kendo UI datepicker displaying wrong date for arabic culture

Tags: c#, telerik-mvc

Model date for english culture :- 3/28/2018  and same model date for arabic culture:- 11/07/39.
I have a page with datepicker, it is binded with model date. For the same page with **english** culture, the date is shown as ex: **3/28/2018**  and for the same page when i change the culture to **arabic** then the date is selected as **11/07/39**.

I don't understand why it is happening and how to fix it. Please help me in this. Thanks

Comment: by default the culture is set to `en-us` if you wish to set the format for your expected culture maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30214813/wrong-currency-unit-in-kendo/30220795#30220795

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks, as per the above link it is displaying correctly for arabic culture also. But here the problem is when i pass selected date from en datepicker to a controller through ajax jquery call then it is working as expected. But for the same datepicker with ar culture, the selected date is not passing to the same controller. Here it is written in console that date(datetime param of controller) can't be null.

Comment: two questions. 1) Is there a reason for the back end system to be configured differently to the front end culture wise? 2) If the answer to question 1 is Yes then why not convert the date to a string in the format of dd MMM yyyy before sending it back to the controller.

Comment: Thanks David. Now am able to pass that date to controller after converting it into string format.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the format of this datepicker and the culture is set server-side you can use this:

```
@Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.Date).Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern)
```